# How do i solve this trivial issue about formatting mail? Java

Tags: java, sendmail

My web application sends mail to its users. Everything is working fine, but my html doesn't get rendered in yahoo.

If i send mail contents as :-

```
<div>
Hello user
<br/>
How are you?
</div>
```

It gets rendered as it is :(. The html is not interpreted by yahoo. How do i solve this problem? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to set the mime type of the message to `text/html`. What is your email sending code?

Comment: oops! Thanks i had "text/plain". Changed it. Now it's working fine

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure you send the message with content type text/html? I usually send messages as multipart messages with one HTML version and one plain text version in order to make sure everybody can read my emails.